# How can I get TextMate's QuickLook plugin to render HAML and YML files?

Tags: textmate, quicklook, uti

TextMate's QL generators are supposed to render QL views for files that TM recognizes, while TM is open. Out of the box, it only renders the basic ones (C, Perl, etc), but [this article on Ciaran Walsh's Blog](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/15/quicklook-and-textmate) explains how to add other UTIs to the generator, to have them rendered properly.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with Dynamic UTIs which are the only type I can find for HAML and YML files (dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80u2prru and dyn.ah62d4rv4ge81w5pq on my system) using PathFinder's ShowInfo command.

Is there a way to use Dynamic UTIs in the TM QL generator's info.plist? Are there standard UTIss for HAML and YML files? Or am I out of luck?

Comment: Just define your own UTIs for these file types.

Comment: But the UTIs are dynamic, so I would be constantly having to update them, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic UTIs are assigned to unknown file types so they *have* a UTI other than "data".

I suggest you define UTIs for file extensions `.haml` and `.yml` and use them in your custom QLGenerator. [See this post on SU](https://superuser.com/a/230250/22317). The linked topic also contains another answer that suggests to use a QuickLook plugin for the `public.data` UTI every file falls back on.