# How do I get QuickLook in macOS to display `.mojo` files?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

- macOS 13.6 Ventura
- Mac Mini M1

Can someone remind me how to get QuickLook to display `.mojo` files, or any unknown file to display its contents. Some of my code source files display with code highlighting and everything, but `.mojo` files do not even display in plain text. There's nothing special about `.mojo` files; they're just plain text files. Indeed, I've already got them configured to open in Cursor editor when double-clicked. It's just [space] that doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! Spotlight uses file types and I’m not familiar with that extension. Could you use the command line tool `mdls` to show us the file type(s) of a representative file? KMDItemKind and kMDItemContentType & kMDItemContentTypeTree are most relevant for quick look plug in to render a preview within finder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuA9p.jpg open terminal app and type **mdls** then drag in one or more of the mojo files and drop on the terminal window  and press return

Comment: More details on the [subsequent fix may be here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206908/5472) or [over here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39230/5472) or [perhaps there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167043/5472)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bmike 
`ask.different` puts a limit on the length of replies, it seems, but these are the two sections you mentioned...

kMDItemContentType                 = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80455nr6"
kMDItemContentTypeTree          = (
    "public.item",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80455nr6",
    "public.data"
)

Comment: Awesome, you can always edit the post if needed. The links I provided have apps that provide importers for public.data which is the most generic file type possible. Installing apps could also add proper typing for those files. What framework or language are they?

Comment: I'm trying to use the 3 backticks in order to put the text in a mono-spaced font, but `ask.different` won't have it! In answer to your last question, `.mojo` files are plain text files which hold source code for the Mojo programming language which is essentially a compiled super-set of Python! I'll check out those links. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect. Pycharm might be an excellent editor to install (and VSCode too) if they add importer for python files, they might carry over to mojo and you don’t have to use them at all.

Comment: I tried the "solution for 2021"  at the bottom of this page, but while pressing space on a `.mojo` file now brings up a window, it doesn't show much, unless they're using the white text on a white background approach 

Comment: I'm using Cursor which is an AI powered VSCode clone, for which there is already (Mojo is a very young language!) a very capable plugin with syntax highlighting. It's really just the QuickView capability I'm after.

Comment: [Qlstephen and peek should be top of the list then](https://github.com/Correia-jpv/fucking-quick-look-plugins)